# Google Analytics: How to associate an event with an individual session

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a variable that's being laoded on my page and then being reported back to GA via the event tracking api. Is there a way for this "event" to be associated with the flow of an individual session?

For example: If I have a variable that gets reported as "eligible", can I then associate this event with the session and page flows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create an advanced segment. That is a way to filter sessions (visits) according to certain criteria. In this case, your criterion would be "Include: Event Label = 'the name of the label of your event'".

Note that it is against the terms of use of GA though to report data on an indidivual basis, i.e. it is not allowed to create an event label that allows you to identify each single session.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Lukas. I wodner if it is against the TOC for the enterprise version. I'll have to look into it. Thanks again.